# Phpmyadmin. mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): Permission denied. Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed

Tags: php, mysql, linux, phpmyadmin, lamp

I have setup my wsl environment, successfully installed Apache, mysql, and php.
I can access mysql in my command line, only by using "sudo -u root -p"

I can't login to phpmyadmin,even with using the correct username and password.
I've attached picture below to give a clear picture.

[phpmyadmin website error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kzgyk.png)

[ubuntu command line error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aI3o.png)

Answer (score 10):

In File /etc/phpmyadmin/config-db.php

change

$dbserver='localhost';

to

$dbserver='127.0.0.1';

Restart Apache2 ;-)

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: This did the trick for me on Rocky9 with mariadb 10.6. The more interesting thing is that when the entry resolves to "localhost" SELinux is blocking. If you set it to permissive then I was able to login even with the entry set to "localhost".

Comment: Saved me a lot of time! On clean Ubuntu 22.04, everything default

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem. I'm using ubuntu 20.04 using wsl. Created the lamp server with php7.3. Created new user with full privilege's. From root & from other user, getting the same error.

**But I got the solution:**
Now first we need to install **Selinux**. Here are the commands:

**Step 1** - Install Selinux:

```
sudo apt install policycoreutils selinux-utils selinux-basics
```

**Step 2** - Activate:

```
sudo selinux-activate
```

**Step 3** - Activate httpd_can_network_connect_db 1:

By default, the policy httpd_can_network_connect_db is disabled (meaning that your web server cannot contact a remote DB.)
Check this via:

```
getsebool -a | grep httpd
```

If httpd_can_network_connect_db is Off, enable it via:

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

**Step 4** - Maybe need to change:
change localhost to 127.0.0.1 in /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```

**Step 6** - Restart mysql & apache:

```
sudo service mysql start
sudi service apache2 start.
```

Comment: I faced the same problem, And got the solution by doing these steps.

Answer (score 2):

In  **/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php**, simply uncomment line **$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';**

Comment: Could you elaborate on why would that help?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My server's Selinux was enforcing and the below parameter was disabled, so I just enabled it and could access the DB from phpMyAdmin UI.

**# getsebool -a | grep httpd_can_network_connect_db**

**httpd_can_network_connect_db --> off**

**# setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1**